# Why do I bind 1 CPU in a multi-thread program that executes much faster than multiple CPUs?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a test program to start two threads as following.

When I use the Process.ProcessorAffinity binding to limit the use only of 1 CPU, the  program takes 45.8683742 seconds to execute and the CPU 2 which it is almost no time to use the Operating System kernel program here.

[image: 1CPU usage of 1CPU in Task Manager]

When I use the Process.ProcessorAffinity binding to limit the use only of 2 CPU, the  program takes 67.733864 seconds to execute and the CPU 1,2 which they are almost no time to use the Operating System kernel program here.

[image: 2 CPUs usage of 1CPU in Task Manager]

When I use the Process.ProcessorAffinity binding to limit the use only of 3 CPU, the  program takes 116.8519694 seconds to execute and the CPU 1,2,3 which they are uses more time of Operating System kernel program.

[image: 3 CPUs usage of 1CPU in Task Manager]

When I use the Process.ProcessorAffinity binding to limit the use only of 8 CPU, the  program takes 132.9382714 seconds to execute and the all CPU  which they are uses more time of Operating System kernel program.

[image: 4 CPUs usage of 1CPU in Task Manager]

I don't know what happened, can someone help explain?

```
    class Program
{
    private static long counter = 0;
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)7;

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(MyMethod);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(MyMethod);

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Sum is {counter}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total is {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} Sec");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key for continuing...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void MyMethod()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < int.MaxValue; index++)
        { Interlocked.Increment(ref counter); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fucntion make no sense, especially not for Multitasking testing purposes. Please provide us with the **actuall** Operations so we can tell you if multithreading has any **hope** of accelerating the execution.

Comment: I know that the MyMethod will be a race conditio and my intention just simulating a lot of computational work.

Comment: @Christopher 
I have changed the MyMethod() using Interlocked.Increment Method to avoid race condition and update my test program and CPU usage of Task Manager. I got same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, you were trying to force a race condition with that counter. The problem here is that every CPU has layers upon layers of caches.

While the CPU and Runtime can not guarantee there is **no** race condition, it will at least do it's best to not actively **cause** one. And few things could cause them as quickly as any of hte 3 layers of caches being out of synch.

For example, if Core 1 changes the value of counter in it's Layer 1 cache that change will be focefully propagated to the Layer 3 cache - and then up into every cores layer 1 cache.

There is still room for a Race Condition from the fact that the operation is `counter = counter + 1`. While you asumed the operation would be purely CPU bound, the flushing of the caches actually forces it to be memory bound.